# Schottky diode part of a laser power supply enable circuit

Tags: power-supply, analog, diodes, schottky

[image: Circuit from AN90]

In this circuit from Jim Williams' AN90 the enable line pulls down the base of Q1 through Q2, through a Schottky diode (1n5712). Why is this Schottky diode there? I imagine it's a Schottky diode so it has a diode drop smaller than Q1's, so it's possible to turn off Q1... but why does it need to be there at all? It seems as if you could short over it and prevent Q1 from conducting just fine. It must be there for a reason! He even seems to omit it in an earlier figure (http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/application-note/an90f.pdf Fig. 2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q2 also pulls down the left side input voltage, which sets the laser current, through the right-facing 1N4148 diode. The Schottky diode keeps these two functions separate.

Without the Schottky, a low voltage output from A1 could pull the current control input low, limiting the input voltage to some value that depends on the laser's forward voltage. There would also be a positive feedback path which could lead to oscillation.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Okay then to be clear, when Q2 is conducting, and say input is at 2.5 volts, the 1n4148 diode will be forward biased and A1+ will be at Vf of the 1n4148, right? So this thing pulls A1+ down to ~1 V. Seems like you'd wanna use a transistor to pull it to ground, right?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the Schottky diode is there to prevent current flowing to base of Q1 through the normal diode that also connects to Q2.  If the voltage at the base of Q1 is then higher than it should be for a specified current, then A1 will begin sinking current.  If the Schottky diode is replaced with a short, and the input A1+ voltage minus (one diode drop) is greater than the target Q1 base voltage, then the normal diode will begin conducting.  This will cause the A1+ voltage to drop, which will cause the A1 output voltage to drop further.  Without doing the stability calculations, I will assume that output of A1 reacts slowly enough that the circuit does not begin to oscillate, but the set current is no longer (INPUT - A1 bias current * 10kOhm)/10; it is now offset by (diode current * 10kOhm/10).

To put it another way, he wanted to pull both Q1's base and A1+ low if the enable pin was high, but did not want to use two transistors, so he used diodes to prevent current flow between A1's output and A1+.